What qualifies as "low-level" or "high-level" feature in machine/deep learning?
The terms "low-level" and "high-level" features usually appear when discussing about CNNs. For example: (excerpt taken from Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R)

The network first identifies low-level features in the input image,
such as small edges, patches of color, and the like. These low-level
features are then combined to form higher-level features, such as
parts of ears, eyes, and so on. Eventually, the presence or absence of
these higher-level features contributes to the probability of any
given output class.

Why "eyes" are considered "higher-level" (aka more "abstract) features compared to edges?
Is there a consensus of what qualifies as "low-level" and "high-level" feature in deep learning or machine learning in general?

I don't think there is a consensus on what is a high-level feature in general, but I think relative ordering does not cast any doubt in the context of state of the art ML and DL applications. Objects are detected as a collection of edges, and that makes an "eye" a higher-level feature compared to an "edge". So, in general, a higher-level concept is made of lower-level building blocks. A "human" is probably a higher-level concept compared to "eye" because you need two eyes and a set of other things to define a human.
Without loss of generality, in a parallel universe, we could have an ML algorithm that first detects "eyes" but nothing else and using those "eyes", it could try to detect edges based on those "eyes". But, probably, no ML model has been found/used in this way. This is just an example how it could go in another direction.

CNNs especially for features of images are processed in a sequential layered hierarchical manner instead of a recursive possibly complicated multi-nested tree structure like the common syntax parser of NLPs. Therefore lower level features are just early layers in the network while high-level features refer to latter layers, and obviously there's no exact clear demarcation between the two.
Most low level features of images include edges (via edge detectors like Sobel filters or other gradient-based filters.), corners (via filters applied in both horizontal and vertical directions), simple patterns of textures (color, brightness, stripes, grids, or other repetitive patterns), color gradients or variations, and basic mereological composing shapes, etc.
Most high level features include apparent parts of objects (eyes, ears, branches), segregated whole object (face, cat), semantic concepts (emotions, gesture, style), and (background) scene-level features and types (mountain view, urban street), etc.
